# Delete a program from registry

Tags: vbscript, registry

I have a vbscript for adding a file to the registry, so on windows startups it opens automatically.

```
Dim WSHShell
Set WSHShell=Wscript.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
WSHShell.RegWrite 
"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run\" ,"C:\test\test.appref-ms","REG_SZ"
```

Now I'd like to prevent this file to open on startups and I need a vbscript for that. Do you have a solution? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not aware of a way to remove a default value via `RegDelete`. WMI would work, though:

```
Const HKCU = &h80000001
path = "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run"
GetObject("winmgmts://./root/default:StdRegProv").DeleteValue HKCU, path, ""
```